# Trouble with Left String in Batch File

Tags: windows, string, batch-file

I'm probably missing something silly, but I'm very new to scripting. I'm trying to create a small batch file that will let me drop an image file onto it, and imagemagick will crop and then rename the output file appropriately (based off the first 6 characters of the original filename and a suffix):

```
@echo off
Set CardName=%1
Set CardFront=%CardName:~0,6%
convert.exe %1 -crop 459x687+11+19 +repage %CardFront%_card.jpg
exit
```

It works fine until I try to use the Left String function in the third line. Then it doesn't generate any new file at all. No error message, either. Not sure what the issue is, any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: make an : `echo %CardFront% & pause` after the set Cardfront=.... And check if the value is correct

Comment: sachadee, thank you! Trying this showed me that the value it's returning is the first 6 characters of the directory path that the file is located in (instead of the first 6 characters of the file name).. any advice on how to correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what the names being dropped in are, it's a little difficult to tell. I'd be tempted to try

```
@echo off
Set "CardName=%~1"
Set CardFront=%CardName:~0,6%
convert.exe "%~1" -crop 459x687+11+19 +repage "%CardFront%_card.jpg"
exit
```

which should remove any quotes surrounding the supplied name when it's applied to `cardname` and include any space appearing in `cardfront` in the name of the `.jpg`.

So `queen of spades.ext` would become `queen _card.jpg`

---

Given that-didn't-work, and not having `imagemagick`,

```dos
@echo off
Set "CardName=%~1"
Set CardFront=%CardName:~0,6%
ECHO convert.exe "%~1" -crop 459x687+11+19 +repage "%CardFront%_card.jpg"
convert.exe "%~1" -crop 459x687+11+19 +repage "%CardFront%_card.jpg"
pause
exit
```

Which should show the command that the batch is attempting to execute AND the result of the attempted conversion. I suspect that it may be a directory problem. `convert.exe` may not be in your current directory or on the path when the batch runs. You may have to fully-qualify your filenames to direct batch to the appropriate location.

Hmm - maybe add

```
cd "c:\wherever\your\imagemagick\directory\is"
```

on a new line directly after the `@echo off`. That might do wonders. Or set your shortcut "Start in" directory to `imagemagick`'s home - might need to move the batch there, too...

---

Given it's a problem with the setting of `Cardfront`; data supplied is full-path:

in place of

```
Set CardFront=%CardName:~0,6%
```

use

```
for %%a in ("%~1") do Set CardFront=%%~na
Set CardFront=%CardFront:~0,6%
```

Comment: Gave this a try, but unfortunately no difference (so still no file being generated). An example file name would be "u11095_c.jpg" - and ultimately I want the new file to be named "u11095_card.jpg".

Comment: Thanks, Magoo! Per the comment above by sachadee, it does look like a directory problem. Not with the imagemagick portion of it (I'm actually able to run it just fine without attempting the rename), but with getting the CardFront variable to set properly. Right now, it's actually pulling the first 6 characters of the directory path of the file name (which ends up being "C:\fan" instead of "u11095"). Not sure how to correct this, though.